# How to combine 2 -name conditions in find?

Tags: bash, shell, find

I would like to search for files that would not match 2 `-name` conditions. I can do it like so :

```
find /media/d/ -type f -size +50M ! -name "*deb" ! -name "*vmdk"
```

and this will yield proper result but can I join these 2 condition with OR somehow ?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can do this using a negated `-regex`, too:-

```
 find ./ ! -regex  '.*\(deb\|vmdk\)$'
```

Comment: Note that `-regex` is less portable than `-name`.

Comment: Should not be the accepted answer. Question asks for a solution using multiple name patterns with `find -name`. Serge's answer answers that.

Answer (score 294):

yes, you can:

```
find /media/d/ -type f -size +50M ! \( -name "*deb" -o -name "*vmdk" \)
```

Explanation from the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html):

> **!**  *expression* : Negation of a primary; the unary NOT operator.
>
> ( *expression* ): True if expression is true.
>
> *expression* **-o**  *expression*: Alternation of primaries; the OR operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is true.

Note that parenthesis, both opening and closing, are prefixed by a backslash (`\`) to prevent evaluation by the shell.

Comment: If you're doing `-exec` or any other action on the `find` results, remember to parenthese `\( \)` the whole criteria, otherwise `-exec` will apply only to the last `-or`-ed criterion. To work on all of them, parenthese them: `find \( <criterion> -o <criterion> \) -exec <command>`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: one may want to consider -iname instead of -name for case insensitivity

Comment: also `-execdir` is preferable wrt `-exec`

Answer (score 49):

You were close to a solution:

```
find /media/d/ -type f -size +50M -and ! -name "*deb" -and ! -name "*vmdk"
```

You can combine the following logic operators in any sequence:

```
-a   -and      - operator AND
-o   -or       - operator OR
!              - operator NOT
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've actually changed the effect of the user's `find` command. Note that `-a` is the default operator if an explicit operator is missing. Also note that if you use `-o`, there must be a logical grouping of the two name tests.  You do this with `\( ... \)`.

Comment: Absolutely incredible. This 'find' command is changing my life.

Answer (score 8):

You can use regular expressions as in:

```
find /media/d -type f -size +50M ! -regex '\(.*deb\|.*vmdk\)'
```

Backslash is the escape character; `.` matches a single character, and `*` serves to match the previous character zero or more times, so `.*` means match zero or more characters.

Comment: Adding an explanation would make your answer better.

Comment: You're right. Added some explanations.